# Sequencing a set of images using Filmic-blender crashes Blender

Tags: cycles-render-engine, video, filmic-blender

I am using Blender 2.78

I have rendered a set of png images out using Blender's default colormanagement settings, loaded them into the sequencer and output as h264 video.

Then I tried out Filmic Blender, opened up the blend file I was working on, picked the settings I wanted in the colormanagement section and clicked render animation (sequencer checked) then Blender crashed instantly. I've tried a few times and it's consistent.

I ran Blender in a command prompt with --debug-all and the log ended with

```
Output #0, avi, to 'C:\tmp\floursack\0001-0060.avi':
  Metadata:
    ISFT            : Lavf55.19.104
    Stream #0:0, 0, 1/24: Video: h264 (libx264) (H264 / 0x34363248), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 1/24, q=10-51, 15000 kb/s, 24 tbn, 24 tbc
Evaluate all animation - 1.000000
Error: EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION
```

Any ideas on how to fix this? Do I need to render the individual images with the Filmic Blender colormanagement options for the sequencer to work with them?

Comment: Filmic should be in the 2.79 release. Then you can file a bug report. Until then you'd have to contact its developer (though Troy_s should read this here soon). The problem here is, that this site is not suitable for bug reports... They are considered off topic.